# Website Format with Stripe Elements Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, stripe-payments

Okay, so I'm somewhat newer with HTML, CSS and JS and am basically self-teaching myself similar to how I did with Ruby and such. I'm building out a website for the woodburnings I make in my free time and am debating on selling these with Stripe.

My website is pretty simple. Just a basic "Hey, this is me" section with little details added in there but it's still a WIP. I had the website with a good layout and was working to fix the format of it, but I went to add in Elements and it all got kind of messy and my Elements doesn't even work as the console shows an error stating `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>`

The CSS for my Elements is affecting the whole page but not really sure how to fix this. I was thinking create a div to hold my Elements but that seemed to have failed.

Any ideas? This is my Codepen: https://codepen.io/Codekraker95/pen/mdyNwPR and code:

```js
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51HB2tdFCmZwjd6e5ahMS1F7NWJLN5CqIOuoH4d0Hzdes1zQg5YroBi98aNTC5iLST3BwNbQGe1xw0ygB53qa1RE100UjsyFKg3');
var elements = stripe.elements({
  fonts: [{
    family: 'Open Sans',
    weight: 400,
    src: 'local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3ZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format("woff2")',
    unicodeRange: 'U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215',
  }, ]
});

var card = elements.create('card', {
  hidePostalCode: false,
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#F99A52',
      color: '#32315E',
      lineHeight: '48px',
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7DF',
      }
    },
  }
});
card.mount('#card-element');

function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {

    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var extraDetails = {
    name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
    email_address: form.querySelector('input[name=email-address]').value
  };
  stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
});
```

```css
h1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  background-image: url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/2nix/2nix1302/2nix130200028/17887014-big-brown-wood-plank-wall-texture-background.jpg');
  position: relative;
  left: 500px;
  top: 1px;
}

h3 {
  height: 30px;
}

p {
  border: 300px;
  color: black;
}

span {
  font-style: italic;
}

.hClass {
  color: black;
}

#linkID {
  color: black;
}

#impID {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#spanID {
  font: white;
}


/*Elements starts here*/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3ZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}

* {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #F6F9FC;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  color: #6A7C94;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

label>span {
  width: 115px;
}

.field {
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #CFD7DF;
  border-radius: 24px;
  color: #32315E;
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: text;
}

.field::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #CFD7DF;
}

.field::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #CFD7DF;
}

.field:focus,
.field.StripeElement--focus {
  border-color: #F99A52;
}

button {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #6F0CCC 0%, #F99A52 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), inset 0 -1px 0 0 #E57C45;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  outline: none;
}

button:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #6F0CCC 0%, #F99A52 100%);
}

button:active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #6F0CCC 0%, #F99A52 100%);
}

.outcome {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  min-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.success,
.error {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.success.visible,
.error.visible {
  display: inline;
}

.error {
  color: #E4584C;
}

.success {
  color: #F8B563;
}

.success .token {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1 class="hClass">Cody's Hot Woodburnings</h1>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3 class="hClass">About Me</h3>

    <p>I create fantastic woodburned images in my spare time.</p>

    <p> I've been woodburning since I was 8 years old with my dad and it used to be the only time we had with each other So it's a hobby I treasure dearly.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Feel free to check out my gallery and then message me with <span id="impID">any</span> questions!</p>

    <h3 class="hClass">Contact:</h3>
    <a id="linkID" href="https://www.gmail.com/">Let me know your thoughts!</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3 class="hClass">Gallery:</h3>
    <img src="https://i.etsystatic.com/13607553/r/il/da7359/1857097635/il_570xN.1857097635_cdq7.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3 class="hClass">Art Types:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span id="spanID">Landscapes</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span id="spanID">Oriental Art</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span id="spanID">Portraits</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!--Elements starts here-->
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <form>
      <label>
              <span>Name</span>
              <input name="cardholder-name" class="field" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
            </label>
      <label>
              <span>Phone</span>
              <input class="field" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" type="tel" />
            </label>
      <label>
              <span>Email Address</span>
              <input name="email-address" class="field" placeholder="12345" />
            </label>
      <label>
              <span>Card</span>
              <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
            </label>
      <button type="submit">Confirm Payment</button>
      <div class="outcome">
        <div class="error"></div>
        <div class="success">
          Payment Successful!
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In javascript you are referencing: `'input[name=address-zip]'` but that field doesn't exist in your html. Also your body tag should be wrapping the HTML not be within it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna make those changes and see where it leaves me. I changed the ZIP section in my HTML to collect emaill address and completely forgot it was on my JavaScript too, rip

Comment: I edited my question to show the current code I'm using.

My Elements now works now and creates Tokens like it should (I have no backend code built out so this works) but just need to fix my website page to be neater.

The CSS for it is all messy. I added the <body> </body> tags to encompass all of my HTML but the format of the website stayed the same. I'll continue playing with this and then edit as needed.

Feel free to leave more suggestions if anybody has some!

Comment: Try to remove 'display: flex;' from the style of your body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in your HTML, f.i. `div` with no closing tag and with the image.

Here the revised HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
  <h1 class="hClass">Cody's Hot Woodburnings</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 class="hClass">About Me</h3> 
  
  <p>I create fantastic woodburned images in my spare time.</p>
 
  <p> I've been woodburning since I was 8 years old with my dad and it used to be the only time we had with each other So it's a hobby I treasure dearly.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Feel free to check out my gallery and then message me with <span id="impID">any</span> questions!</p>
  
  <h3 class="hClass">Contact:</h3>
  <a id="linkID"href="https://www.gmail.com/">Let me know your thoughts!</a>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 class="hClass">Gallery:</h3>
  <img src="https://i.etsystatic.com/13607553/r/il/da7359/1857097635/il_570xN.1857097635_cdq7.jpg" />
</div>

<div>
  <h3 class="hClass">Art Types:</h3>
  <ul>                             
   <li>                           
      <span id="spanID">Landscapes</span>  
   </li>                        
   <li>                           
      <span id="spanID">Oriental Art</span>  
   </li>                          
   <li>                           
      <span id="spanID">Portraits</span>
   </li>                          
 </ul>

<!--Elements starts here-->
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <form>
    <label>
      <span>Name</span>
      <input name="cardholder-name" class="field" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Phone</span>
      <input class="field" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" type="tel" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Email Address</span>
      <input name="email-address" class="field" placeholder="12345" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Card</span>
      <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Confirm Payment</button>
    <div class="outcome">
      <div class="error"></div>
      <div class="success">
        Payment Successful!
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ale! I also removed display:flex as you mentioned which helped fix the positioning of my CSS itself and added the revised HTML as well.